# failed to compute cache key: "/app" not found: not found azure pipeline

Tags: docker, azure-devops, dockerfile, azure-pipelines

I am running a pipeline with docker file,but i am getting below error.

```
failed to compute cache key: "/app" not found: not found
##[error]The process 'C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin\docker.exe' failed with exit code 1
```

I have taken donet code from github which consist of docker file,i tried add docker and ran the build.

My docker file.

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-aspnetcore-runtime
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./app /app 
ENTRYPOINT [ "dotnet", "Shop.Web.dll"]
```

my docker ignore file has:

```
bin\
obj\
```

Comment: There is no `/app` directory in the same directory as your Dockerfile at build time.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you to check your `buildContext` argument, you provide that via your Build task as well as making sure you have app in that directory defined by `buildContext`